# on Session time out redirect to one of two different log in screens dependent on query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this historic site that is inertly broken and is in the process of being replaced. how ever until the replace site it ready I have to maintain this site.

the Issue is I have a site that needs to know the group code of the logged in user.  for example I have two groups  Group1 and Group2.

on the login page by default the is simply .../login.aspx  and that will store in the session  (group = Group1) and if if the use goes to the log in page with .../login.aspx?group=Group2  then they have Group2 stored in the session instead.

the reason for why this was done this way was before my time by it is a very complex login screen for authentication and is needed to set the site up for multiple session variable.
saying this it means that replacing the log in page is not an option at this stage.

what I need to a way that when the session times out the user is directed back to the correct variation of the login page and also to remember the page that they were on so they can be returned to this page.

minimum solution is to have them redirected back to the correct login version, the taking back to the page they were on after resigning is only a "would like" feature.

can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this,  the on Session end event doesn't seem to work as the session is gone at that point so nothing to compare against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the login page, have it store in a cookie group1 or group2 after the login is successful.  When the login page loads, check to see if your group cookie is present.  If there is one, you can then do redirect to the appropriate login URL.

Comment: yes, that is the path I ended up going down, thanks  I ended up having to use the cookie and a query string to identify the session timed or / error occured. then I process the vlaue of the cookie.   how ever if the page is accessed and the cookie is present but the query string isn't present then it progresses as if the cookie wasn't there.  Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this.

As you stated, in the Session_End event (presumably you are using InProc session for this event to be fired) - there is no session to figure out which group the user was in.  Even if you could get the session variables, there is no HttpContext in the Session_End event, as it occurs on server, without an Http Request - so you wont be able to redirect.

This event could fire with the site sitting at a screen at which point, Forms Authentication will redirect back to the login screen, or could occur long after the user has closed the browser.

**Edit - More information needed**

Are you using InProc session and Forms Authentication for the application?

If so, one possible solution is to create an HttpModule that could run before FormsAuthentication would recognise that the Session/Auth Cookie in the request had expired and redirected back to sign in.

As Blam said - if you store the info in another data store - you can get at this from the HttpModule, and do a custom redirect from there.

Be warned that the HttpModule would run for every request, so any Db calls etc could be a performance drain.

Comment: If it is not an answer then it is a comment.  Even if there is no answer.

Comment: I cant comment on other peoples questions yet - you need at least 15 rep for that :)

Comment: OK a Session_End will by definition occur without a Request. But a Session_End does not need to redirect.  A Request cannot occur without a Request.  The Request is going to pass a SessionID as the Request is not aware that it's session has ended.

Answer (score 0):

But you do have SessionID.  In a db or other store associate the SessionID with the group.

[HttpSessionState.SessionID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)